# Is "bird's eye point of view" considered informal?

Tags: formality, science

I am writing a scientific paper, and I want to convey the idea that one advantage of a centralized management approach is that it provides a "bird's eye point of view." However, I found few other papers that use this expression, particularly in my research field. Is it considered informal? Is there a better way to express this?

Comment: Are you trying to say it gives you a view from high in the sky? What point are you trying to convey with "a bird's eye point of view"?

Comment: Just because you can't find some expression in some field of research does not make it informal. ***Sometimes a bird's eye view can be called an overview***. Not everything has already been written. And the entire idea is very anxiety-provoking (to me). I am sure there are potentially thousands of expressions such as this that have not yet used in some field of research or other.

Comment: Consider 'high level overview'?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "few". Assuming Google Scholar's numbers are accurate, there are more than a few, see [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22bird%27s+eye+view%22) and [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q="birds+eye+view"). Some of these use the expression to mean "top down view", others use it to mean "overview".

Comment: As noted by Lambie, the idiomatic expression in English is **bird's eye view,** not "bird's eye point of view." So it's either a "high point of view" (i.e.,  "overview") or a "bird's eye view," which *might* be considered too informal for a scientific paper. But don't mix them.

Comment: Bird's eye view is good, so is 'executive summary' and 'broad sweep.'

Comment: Let me try to give some context: In computer networks, distributed management means that each computer only knows the state of the network through its neighbours. Centralized management means that a central controller has the global network state and everyone can just query this entity that has a **bird's eye view** of the network. I am not sure that _overview_ conveys this idea. Did I make myself clear?

Comment: @MarkHubbard I don't know if I'm being too meticulous, but my intention was to use "bird's eye point of view". The idea is "to build something **_from_** a  bird's eye point of view". I don't know if "to build something from a _bird's eye view_" means the same thing. (Maybe I should mention that english is not my native language.)

Comment: You were perfectly clear, but what you are describing is a ***complete view*** of the network, not a "bird's eye point of view." "Bird's eye view" is a standard expression in English. If you use "bird's eye *point* of view," you will sound like a non-native English speaker. This is the problem with using idioms: if you don't use them correctly, they will not sound natural and professional. (Otherwise, your English is very good!)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it is fine to use this phrase in a scientific paper, but there are other better ways to convey this. "A Bird's Eye View" or "a bird's eye point of view" can be confused with a top-down view. I think the word you are looking for is "overview".

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, you could say a strategic (or high-level, as opposed to tactical or low-level) view; more concerned with the bigger picture and goals than the details of how to accomplish them.

Answer (score 0):

From an engineering technical position, a bird's eye view is called the "plan view". This may be useful.